# How can i build a texture similar to a tennis ball

Tags: texturing, shaders

i am trying to make a texture similar to either a tennis ball, or a towel. I know they are quite different, but I was wondering if something in between the two were possible to create as a procedural texture. I don't want to use the particle system, and I'd rather not use an image texture. does anybody have any other recommendations?

Comment: set the Roughness to 1 and mix in a Noise texture with high detail.

Comment: I have tried that, but the best I am getting is something that looks more like an orange peal.. sorry for my misunderstanding, but what would I send the noise texture into? i currently have it in my roughness, and another into my bump map.

Comment: You can increase the scale of the Noise to get more detail. Also add a Color Ramp to sharpen the Noise and Mix in a Velvet BSDF and change the Sigma to change the way the light reacts. But if you want high detail you might need to go for a full fluff simulation via particles.